# Disable cache of static block Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, cache, widget, block-cache

How can I disable a widget or static block from being cached inside the Blocks HTML output cache?

The widget loads a specific static block on all CMS pages.
Inside the static block, I load a template by using:

```
{{block type="core/template" template="/page/navigation.phtml" cache_lifetime=0}}
```

But, The template is still being cached. When I disable the Blocks HTML output cache, it works fine.

I also tried to load the static block from my `local.xml` file, with the following. But, the block is still being cached:

```
<cms_page>
    <reference name="left">
        <action method="unsetData"><key>cache_lifetime</key></action>
        <action method="unsetData"><key>cache_tags</key></action>
        <block type="cms/block" name="service_navigatie">
            <action method="setBlockId">
                <block_id>service_navigatie</block_id>
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</cms_page>
```

Comment: which version of magento are you using ?

Comment: @Naveed Sorry! Magento 1.9.3.8

Comment: Have you tried the same with parent blocks in layout? Your code seems right, so probably any parent is being cached

Comment: @RaulSanchez Thanks a good suggestion. Is there a easy way to check what the parent blocks are?

Comment: You can enable Block hinting, in backoffice https://www.classyllama.com/blog/enable-templateblock-hints-in-admin-panel